# Problems updating my code from text-davinci-003 to gpt-3.5-turbo

Tags: openai-api, chatgpt-api

I am just learning coding and trying to figure out how to replicate my own little chat GPT on my website. I have it working for Davinci three but when I try to upgrade to 3.5 it breaks. Here is the working link and the code. Any tips?

https://wellinformedluminouspublishers.benmiller14.repl.co/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>GPT-3 API Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>GPT-3 API Example</h1>
  <div>
    <label for="user-message">Enter a message:</label>
    <input type="text" id="user-message">
    <button onclick="generateResponse()">Generate Response</button>
  </div>
  <div id="response-container"></div>
  
  <script>
    function generateResponse() {
      const url = "https://api.openai.com/v1/completions";
      const apiKey = "API-KEY-HERE";
      const model = "text-davinci-003";
      const userMessage = document.getElementById("user-message").value;
      const payload = {
        prompt: userMessage,
        temperature: 0.7,
        max_tokens: 50,
        model: model
      };
      fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "Authorization": "Bearer " + apiKey
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(payload)
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        const responseContainer = document.getElementById("response-container");
        responseContainer.innerText = data.choices[0].text;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error("Error generating response:", error);
      });
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried just replacing "text-davinci-003" on line 20 with "gpt-3.5-turbo" but it breaks when I do that. I think because it may be a different API endpoint? But I'm not experienced enough with APIs yet to understand how to fix it.

Here is the page on the API update:

https://help.openai.com/en/articles/6283125-what-happened-to-engines

I think I need to change "prompt" to "messages" and maybe change the endpoint url also.  But not sure ...

Comment: Did you mean to paste your `ApiKey` value for public viewing when you pasted your code? It looks like a legit code.

Answer (score 1):

This code works!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>OpenAI API Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="input-form">
      <label for="input-text">Topic: </label>
      <input type="text" id="input-text" name="input-text"><br><br>
      <input type="hidden" id="hidden-field-1" name="hidden-field-1" value="List 10 clickbait titles for a blog article about this topic with the following tone: ">
      <input type="hidden" id="hidden-field-2" name="hidden-field-2" value="Maximum title length should be 60 characters. "><br><br>
      <label for="dropdown-menu">Choose an option:</label>
      <select id="dropdown-menu" name="dropdown-menu">
        <option value="funny">Funny</option>
        <option value="scary">Scary</option>
        <option value="option-3">Option 3</option>
      </select><br><br>

      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <div id="output-div"></div>

    <script>
      const form = document.getElementById('input-form');
      const input = document.getElementById('input-text');
      const output = document.getElementById('output-div');
      const hiddenField1 = document.getElementById('hidden-field-1');
      const hiddenField2 = document.getElementById('hidden-field-2');
      const dropdownMenu = document.getElementById('dropdown-menu');

      form.addEventListener('submit', async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        // Replace with your own OpenAI API key
        const apiKey = 'MY-API_KEY';

        const message = `${input.value}. ${hiddenField1.value} ${dropdownMenu.value}. ${hiddenField2.value}.`;

        const response = await fetch('https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${apiKey}`
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            model: 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
            messages: [{ role: 'user', content: message }],
            temperature: 0.7
          })
        });

        const result = await response.json();

        output.innerHTML = `<p>${result.choices[0].message.content}</p>`;
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to explain why Ben Miller's answer works.

Firstly you need a different url. If you look at the [API documentation](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/completions/create), the url for completion (e.g. text-davinci-003) is https://api.openai.com/v1/completions whereas the url for chat (e.g. gpt-3.5-turbo) is https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions.

You also need different parameters in the request body. Again, check the documentation to see which ones are required. While the completion model needs a prompt, the chat model needs a list of all the messages from the conversation so far.

The response is also structured a bit differently, so you need to use data.choices[0].messages.content instead of data.choices[0].text.

All of this and more is in the documentation I linked to, though there aren't many examples.